# Getting Kotlin version issue while creating release-apk in flutter?

Tags: flutter, kotlin, release-apk

While making flutter release apk its showing an error of

```
┌─ Flutter Fix ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ [!] Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.                            │
│ Find the latest version on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details, then update │
│ D:\Projects\Flutter\Mobile-APP-frontend\android\build.gradle:                                     │
│ ext.kotlin_version = '<latest-version>'
```

I have also added the new version of kotlin like 1.9.10
i have gradle of 7.1.2 version

How to solve that, Thank you.

making flutter release apk, but getting kotlin version issue

Comment: Does anything prevent you from upgrading to the latest versions of your tools? Gradle is now at 8.4 and Kotlin at 1.9.10 (almost 1.9.20), so the usual approach would be to upgrade first before going further

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I needed to update the gradle to 8.4 right? to use the latest Kotlin (1.9.10)

Answer (score 0):

try `ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'` and gradle 7.3.0. You will be able to generate build using latest flutter sdk.

Comment: Do i needed to update into gradle.properties also?

Comment: You can update gradle distribution in the gradle wrapper properties file. and you can specify gradle version in build gradle file using     classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'

Comment: I have gradle-7.5-all.zip in that

Comment: getting this >>>>
* What went wrong:
The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.5.20 and higher.
The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
project ':pdf_merger' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.31

Comment: This dependancy is more than 2 year old and its require lower version of kotlin. You can clone dependancy and upgrade kotlin and gradle version. Then you can use it. Ref: https://pub.dev/packages/pdf_merger

Comment: Mean i needed to update the pdf_merger or downgrade the kotlin version?

Comment: yes. You can do any of them.